# Entity Framework 4.1 T4 Output to IDbset

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I would like to have the T4 template created by visual studio output my entities as IDbset rather than DbSet any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already have a t4 template the generates a `DbContext`. So just edit the T template for the context, which is probably named like `Yourmodelname.Context.tt`. There is a block like this in it (I'm using EF 5):

```
public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
        _code.Escape(entitySet));
}
```

Now change `"{0} DbSet<{1}>` in `"{0} IDbSet<{1}>` and the context will have `IDbSets`.

Side note: if this is part of an operation to mock the context, you should know that that's pretty hopeless.

Comment: What's your reasoning behind thinking mocking the context is hopeless? There seems to be a big differing of opinion on this

Comment: Thanks, I think there is some value in Mocking the context in simple cases but it's limited for sure. We're looking at a mixture of mocking the context and approval tests at the moment. I suspect we'll mostly end up with the latter. Certainly harder than it should be to unit test this stuff